# Word usage: serme

Tags: uso-de-palabras, definiciones, reflexivos

I've come across the below sentence:

> Este año he decidido serme fiel a mi misma y no mentirme

I checked the dictionary and couldn't find the word "serme". What does it mean?

Comment: As an aside, "a mi misma" is redundant in the sentence. "Serme fiel" implies it. "Este año he decidido serme fiel y no mentirme".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

serme = ser + me and means "to be" in its infinitive reflexive form. "Mentirme" is of the same form, mentir + me.

> This year I decided to be faithful to myself and not lie to myself.

You can add the reflexive pronouns to the end of infinitives, gerunds and affirmative imperative verbs.

Comment: thanks for your comment. Since usually if the word is relfexive, the dictionary will always show somethinglike "serse" or "mentirse". But this time I couldn't find both words this time. Why doesn't the dictionary show that? I used the online dictionary "wordreference.com".

Comment: @ Cadenza : I can't find any examples of it being used either. But I can't see what else they could have meant. Was it from an old book? It certainly appears superfluous as "Este año he decidido ser fiel a mí mismo y no mentirme a mí misma." would mean the same.

Comment: No, it's from a recent article written by someone.

Comment: By the way, why you said "ser fiel a mí mismO" but "mentirme a mí mismA"?

Comment: Finger trouble with cut and paste! "Este año he decidido ser fiel a mí misma y no mentirme" As per your original sentence.